# How to reduce code without inheriting on Symfony, php and html

Tags: php, html, symfony

I am wondering if there is a way I can reduce my code without inheriting.
And what would be the best practice?

I am working with Symfony. I have old code and I need to do some forms.
Most of them are quite similar. 
I have many controllers, and forms and only few differences among them.

Here is an example of a controller.
Only (NAMETOBECHANGED) changes among the controllers.

```
<?php

namespace Data\LiveBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

use Data\LiveBundle\Entity\DataAPatient;
use Data\LiveBundle\Entity\DataDNaMETOBECHANGED;

/**
 * DataDNaMETOBECHANGED controller.
 *
 */
class DataDNaMETOBECHANGEDController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * Lists all DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entities.
     *
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request, $limit, $offset)
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED');
        $qb = $repo->getDefaultQuery();

        return $this->renderIndex($repo, $qb, $limit, $offset, 'default');
    }

    /**
     * Lists all DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entities sorted by a chosen column.
     *
     */
    public function indexSortAction(Request $request, $limit, $offset, $column){
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED');

        $qb = $repo->getDefaultQueryOrdered($column);
        return $this->renderIndex($repo, $qb, $limit, $offset, $column);
    }

    /**
     * Renders the index page
     *
     */
    private function renderIndex($repo, $qb, $limit, $offset, $column)
    {
        //TODO: Add Access-Control 
        if (!$this->isAdmin()) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        //model taken from Events
        //$queryHelper = $this->get('general_commonbundle.util.queryhelper');
        //$qb = $queryHelper->addProjectFilter($qb);
        //if(!$this->isAdmin()){
            //$qb = $queryHelper->addAccessControl($qb);
        //}

        $total = $repo->countQueryResults($qb);
        $qb = $repo->addLimitToQuery($qb, $limit, $offset);

        $paginationOptions = array(
            'total' => $total,
            'limit' => $limit,
            'offset' => $offset
        );

        $entities = $repo->getResults($qb);


        //TODO: lock dataset if 180 days passed.
        $editable = array();
        foreach($entities as $entity){
            $this->isAdmin(); // TODO: owner check: $editable[$entity->getPKpPatientid()] = $this->isOwner($entity->getPKpPatientid())
        }

        // Disable softdelete filter, such that view can access all foreign keys.
        // View needs to distinguish between still existent foreign keys and deleted ones.
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if (array_key_exists('softdeleteable', $em->getFilters()->getEnabledFilters())) {
            $em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
        }

        return $this->render('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
            'editable' => $editable,
            'paginationOptions' => $paginationOptions,
            'orderColumn' => $column,
            'parentRoute' => $this->generateUrl('datadnaMeTOBECHANGED')
        ));
    }


    /**
     * Finds and displays an DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity.
     *
     */
    public function showAction($pKpPatientid)
    {
        if (!$this->isAdmin()) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED')->find($pKpPatientid);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity.');
        }

        // Access control
        if($this->isAdmin() // || $this->isOwner($pKpPatientid)
            ) {
            // allow access
        }
        else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        // Disable softdelete filter, such that view can access all foreign keys.
        // View needs to distinguish between still existent foreign keys and deleted ones.
        if (array_key_exists('softdeleteable', $em->getFilters()->getEnabledFilters())) {
            $em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
        }
        $editable = $this->isAdmin(); //$this->isOwner($entity->getPKpPatientid()) 

        $print = $this->getRequest()->get('print') == '1';

        return $this->render('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'editable' => $editable,
            'isPreview' => false,
            'print' => $print,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Redirects to preview a new DataAPatient entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->isAdmin()) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $entity = new DataAPatient();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity->setPDateOfBirth(new \DateTime('now'));
//         $entity->setTimeStart(new \DateTime('now'));
//         $entity->setTimeEnd(new \DateTime('now'));

        $newForm = $this->createNewForm($entity);

        $entity->setDatetimeCreated( new \DateTime('now') );
        $entity->setDatetimeChanged (new \DateTime ('now'));
        //TODO: set SNNID

        $newForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($newForm->isValid()) {
            if($newForm->get('submit')->isClicked()){//Save
            $pKpPatientid = $this->storeNewDataAPatient($entity);
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dataapatient_sendMessage', array("pKpPatientid" => $pKpPatientid)));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED:form.html.twig', array(
            'entity'     => $entity,
            'form'   => $newForm->createView(),
            'isNew'=> true,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a new DataAPatient entity.
     *
     * @param DataAPatient $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form
     *
     */
    private function createNewForm(DataAPatient $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm($this->get('data_livebundle.form.dataapatienttype'), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('dataapatient_new'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));
        return $form;
    }



    /**
     * Redirects to preview changes made to an existing DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity.
     *
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, $pKpPatientid)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED')->find($pKpPatientid);
        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity.');
        }

        //Access control
        if (!$this->isAdmin() //&& !$this->isOwner($pKpPatientid)
            ) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($editForm->isValid()) {

            //Refresh Changed-Date
            $entity->setDatetimeChanged( new \DateTime('now') );
            //Set naMeTOBECHANGEDAgeRef in DataDNaMETOBECHANGED
            $entity->getDNaMETOBECHANGED()->setNaMETOBECHANGEDAgeRef (round($entity->getDNaMETOBECHANGED()->getNaMETOBECHANGEDAgeCalc(),0));

            if($editForm->get('submit')->isClicked()){//Save
                $em->persist($entity);
                //Store changes
                $pKpPatientid = $this->storeEditedDataDNaMETOBECHANGED($entity);

                //TODO: log changes in history
                if($editForm->get('submit')->isClicked()){
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('datadnaMeTOBECHANGED_show', array('pKpPatientid' => $pKpPatientid)));
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->render('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED:form.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'isNew' => false,
        ));
    }


    /**
     * Creates a form to edit a DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity.
     *
     * @param DataDNaMETOBECHANGED $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createEditForm(DataDNaMETOBECHANGED $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm($this->get('data_livebundle.form.datadnaMeTOBECHANGEDtype'), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('datadnaMeTOBECHANGED_edit', array('pKpPatientid' => $entity->getPKpPatientid())),
            'method' => 'POST'
        ));
        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save Changes'));

        return $form;
    }


    /**
     * Persists changes made to an existing DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity to the database
     *
     */
    private function storeEditedDataDNaMETOBECHANGED($entity)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity.');
        }
        $pSnnid = $entity->getPSnnid();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add(
                'notice',
                'Your changes to the DataDNaMETOBECHANGED of ID: "'.$pSnnid. '" was saved!'
        );

        return $entity->getPKpPatientid();
    }

    /**
     * Persists a new DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity to the database
     *
     */
    private function storeNewDataDNaMETOBECHANGED($entity)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity.');
        }
        $pSnnid = $entity->getPSnnid();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add(
            'notice', 'The new DataDNaMETOBECHANGED for "'.$pSnnid. '" was saved!'
        );

        return $entity->getPKpPatientid();
    }


    /**
     * Removes hospital entity from the database by pKpPatientid
     *
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $pKpPatientid)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED')->find($pKpPatientid);
        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find DataDNaMETOBECHANGED entity.');
        }

        //Access control
        if (!$this->isAdmin()) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $pSnnid = $entity -> getPSnnid();
        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
                'notice',
                'The DataDNaMETOBECHANGED for "'.$pSnnid.'" was deleted successfully!'
        );

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('datadnaMeTOBECHANGED'));
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether current user has role ROLE_ADMIN
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    private function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether current user has ID '$pKpPatientid'
     *
     * @param mixed $pKpPatientid The entity id which current user wants to edit
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    private function isOwner($pKpPatientid)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // Disable softdeletable filter (only if it's not already inactive)
        if (array_key_exists('softdeleteable', $em->getFilters()->getEnabledFilters())) {
            $em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
        }
        $entity = $em->getRepository('DataLiveBundle:DataDNaMETOBECHANGED')->find($pKpPatientid);
        $result =  $entity->getFKOwner()->getPKpPatientid() == $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getPKpPatientid();

        // Enable softdeletable filter before returning
        $em->getFilters()->enable('softdeleteable');
        return $result;
    }


}
```

And for HTML, here is an example:

```
     <div class='col-xs-4'>
        <div class='col-xs-7'>{{ form_label(form.dFu2.fu2MdiRaw, 'Cognitive RAW score:', {'label_attr':{'style':'margin-top:3px'}})}}</div>
        <div class='col-xs-2'>{{ form_widget(form.dFu2.fu2MdiRaw, {'attr':{'style':'width:50px'}})}}</div>
      </div>
```

This kind of piece of code repeats itself a lot among the forms. And in each for most of the time only fu1, fu2, fu3, ... change.

Thank your for your advice!

Comment: You need to fragment, fragment and fragment your code !! take a look at SOLID principles, especially the "S" => Single-responsiblity principle

Comment: Ok, thank you!  I will have a look at it.